# Is an algorithm to find whether a given Linear Programming problem is degenerate or not?

Tags: linear-programming

Is there an algorithm to detect the existence of Degeneracy before solving a given  Linear Programming problem by simplex method (search through extreme points)?

Comment: A Linear Programming problem is not degenerate, a pivot of the simplex algorithm eventually is.

Comment: My wording is wrong. But I think you understand my question.

Comment: When Dantzig conceives the extreme point method initially, he did not anticipate the problem of degeneracy; Later he takes this into account.